# blackfin bf537 LED blinking

Tags: c, signal-processing, blackfin

These codes below are the example of LED blinking program for blackfin bf537
the LEDs will blink from right to left and the toggle back.
/**/

```
EX_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(Timer0_ISR)
{
// confirm interrupt handling
*pTIMER_STATUS = 0x0001;

// shift old LED pattern by one, left to right
if(sLight_Move_Direction)
{
    if((ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED >> 1) <= 0x0020) ucActive_LED = 0x1000;
}
else
{
    if((ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED << 1) == 0x0020) ucActive_LED = 0x0020;
}

// write new LED pattern to PORTF LEDs
*pPORTFIO_TOGGLE = ucActive_LED;
```

/**/

Now I am trying to modify codes to accomplish the new function, I want it blink from left to right one time when i push the buttom, so there are my codes below:
/**/

```
EX_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(Timer0_ISR)
{
// confirm interrupt handling
*pTIMER_STATUS = 0x0001;

// shift old LED pattern by one, left to right
if(sLight_Move_Direction){

    ucActive_LED == 0x0800;

    ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED >> 1;

    ucActive_LED == 0x0040; 
}

// write new LED pattern to PORTF LEDs  
*pPORTFIO_TOGGLE = ucActive_LED;
```

/**/

Now it can't work or jus blink LED3, How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You are using == instead of = and you will get a warning "statement with no effect".(The whole thing will be converted to bool). ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED >> 1; can be replaced with ucActive_LED>>1;

Comment: I tried but still not working. Is there anything wrong with the codes or my thought?

Comment: My mistake, it's ucActive_LED>>=1;

Comment: it still cant work..thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few days thinking, here is my answer:

```
int Mode;

EX_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(Timer0_ISR)
{
    // confirm interrupt handling
    *pTIMER_STATUS = 0x0001;

    if(Mode == 1)
    {
    if((ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED >> 1) <= 0x0020) 
        ucActive_LED = 0x1000;
    }
    else if(Mode == 2)
    {
     if((ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED << 1) >= 0x1000) 
     ucActive_LED = 0x0020;             
    }
    else if(Mode == 3)
    {
    if((ucActive_LED = ucActive_LED >> 2) <= 0x0020) 
        ucActive_LED = 0x1000;  
    }


    // write new LED pattern to PORTF LEDs  
    *pPORTFIO = ucActive_LED;  
    }
```

and then set the PORTFIO to push buttons from PF2 to PF5(SW13~SW10)
each button correspond to each mode, therefore we can see that the mode 1 is LEDs are blinking from left to right. Mode 2 is blinking from right to left. And Mode 3 is blinking the LED 2, 4, and 6.